# What does this error states in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, server-error

I have added htaccess file to my codeigniter folder and since then i get

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error and was unable to complete your
>   request. Either the server is
>   overloaded or there was an error in a
>   CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error,
>   please contact the webmaster. Error
>   500 localhost 05/20/10 13:16:23
>   Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
>   mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.5

My htaccess files has this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: belongs on server fault? ...quite literally.

Answer (score 1):

it is not PHP error and it states, as Krab mentioned, "See web-server's error_log for the actual error message"

Answer (score 1):

It's actually Apache error caused by your htaccess.

I think the invalid line is this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
```

The $1 is not defined there.